# why is IntentService's onStartCommand method called every time the service handles a new intent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, intentservice, location-updates

i have a service that receives location updates every 1-3 seconds or so. the service is started from the main activity using a pending intent:

```
    mFusedLocationClientFast.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, getPendingIntent());
```

where `getPendingIntent()` is a method that defines an action for my `IntentService` to handle in `handleIntent()`

however, a strange thing i noticed is that every time the `IntentService` handles a location update in `handleIntent()`, it's always immediately preceded by a call to `onStartCommand()` of the same service.

does anyone know why `onStartCommand()` needs to be called every time the service handles an intent?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

An IntentService is, simply, a Service that runs `onHandleIntent` on a worker thread.  The mechanism by which a Service receives an intent is `onStartCommand`.

In an IntentService, the `onStartCommand` method forwards the intent to the `onHandleIntent` method.

The code is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java)

It is puzzling, to me, that the designers of the `IntentService` did not make its implementations of `onStartCommand` and `onStart` `final`

Comment: got it...so every time onHandleIntent runs to completion, the service is stopped and gets recreated everytime a new location comes in. i guess IntentService probably isn't the best mechanism for this task...i'm trying to make something similar to a run tracker, where you can dynamically view your location throughout the day.